# How to replace read function for procfs entry that returned EOF and byte count read both?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am working on updating our kernel drivers to work with linux kernel 4.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.0.4. The drivers last worked with linux kernel 3.9.2.
In one of the modules, we have a procfs entries created to read/write the on-board fan monitoring values. Fan monitoring is used to read/write the CPU or GPU temperature/modulation,etc. values.

The module is using the following api to create procfs entries:

```
struct proc_dir_entry *create_proc_entry(const char *name, umode_t
mode,struct proc_dir_entry *parent);
```

Something like:

```
struct proc_dir_entry * proc_entry = 
create_proc_entry("fmon_gpu_temp",0644,proc_dir);
proc_entry->read_proc = read_proc;
proc_entry->write_proc = write_proc;
```

Now, the read_proc is implemented something  in this way:

```
static int read_value(char *buf, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data) {
    int len = 0;
    int idx = (int)data;

    if(idx == TEMP_FANCTL)
        len = sprintf (buf, "%d.%02d\n", fmon_readings[idx] / TEMP_SAMPLES, 
              fmon_readings[idx] % TEMP_SAMPLES * 100 / TEMP_SAMPLES);
    else if(idx == TEMP_CPU) {
        int i;
        len = sprintf (buf, "%d", fmon_readings[idx]);
        for( i=0; i < FCTL_MAX_CPUS && fmon_cpu_temps[i]; i++ ) {
            len += sprintf (buf+len, " CPU%d=%d",i,fmon_cpu_temps[i]);
        }
        len += sprintf (buf+len, "\n");
    }
    else if(idx >= 0 && idx < READINGS_MAX)
        len = sprintf (buf, "%d\n", fmon_readings[idx]);
    *eof = 1;
    return len;
}
```

This read function definitely assumes that the user has provided enough buffer space to store the temperature value. This is correctly handled in userspace program. Also, for every call to this function the read value is in totality and therefore there is no support/need for subsequent reads for same temperature value.
Plus, if I use "cat" program on this procfs entry from shell, the 'cat' program correctly displays the value. This is supported, I think, by the setting of EOF to true and returning read bytes count.

New linux kernels do not support this API anymore.

My question is:

How can I change this API to new procfs API structure keeping the functionality same as: every read should return the value, program 'cat' should also work fine and not go into infinite loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **primary user interface** for read files on Linux is [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read). Its pair in kernel space is `.read` function in *struct file_operations*.

*Every other mechanism* for read file in kernel space (*read_proc*, *seq_file*, etc.) is actually an (parametrized) implementation of `.read` function.

> The only way for kernel to return EOF indicator to user space is returning 0 as number of bytes read.

Even `read_proc` implementation you have for 3.9 kernel actually implements `eof` flag as returning 0 on next invocation. And `cat` actually perfoms the *second* invocation of `read` for find that file is end.

(Moreover, `cat` performs *more than 2 invocations of read*: first with 1 as *count*, second with *count* equal to page size minus 1, and the last with remaining *count*.)

The simplest way for "one-shot" read implementation is using *seq_file* in `single_open()` mode.

Comment: I have added the implementation of the read function in the question. I understand I can call the read function as many times from userspace and every time I get an updated temperature value. right ?

also, there are no file offsets maintained here so every call to read here is like reading a variable. program 'cat' works fine with this implementation without going into infinite loop.

Comment: The problem for me is that how do I implement something similar with new kernel api. That is, I should be able to call read multiple times on single file open. If I use seq_file with single_open, I will have to close the file before I can call read the second time, right ?

Comment: `If I use seq_file with single_open, I will have to close the file before I can call read the second time, right?` - Yes, when file is read up to EOF,  you need to reset read position before read it again. It could be done with file reopeing (`close()` + `open()`) or with `lseek()` to position 0. But `single_open()` doesn't mean that you may print only single value to output: inside `.show` function you may execute similar cycles as you have in your `read_proc`. But better way is to use full `seq_file` power with `seq_open()` instead of `single_open()`.